# Unable to scrape dynamic web page

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the table found https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/search/featurefilter.html?productType=873&1_Filter-Family=595&2_StatusCodeText=4

I tried using BeautifulSoup and Soup is unable to parse the info located inside the "body" tag. I get a null output when I try to parse the table.

How can I workaround this?

Comment: `BeautifulSoup`/`LXML` can't run JavaScript - if you turn off javaScrip in browser and load page then you will see what `BeautifulSoup`/`LXML` can get. You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Comment: you can also use `DevTools` in Chrome/Firefox (tab `Network`) to see all requests from server to client and you will see that JavaScript (XHR) get this data from https://ark.intel.com/libs/apps/intel/support/ark/advancedFilterSearch?productType=873&1_Filter-Family=595&2_StatusCodeText=4&forwardPath=/content/www/us/en/ark/search/featurefilter.html&pageNo=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses JavaScript to add data but `BeautifulSoup`/`LXML` can't run JavaScript - if you turn off javaScrip in browser and load page then you will see what BeautifulSoup/LXML can get.

You may need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which can run JavaScript.

Or you can try to use `DevTools` in `Chrome`/`Firefox` (tab `Network) to get url uses`JavaScript`(`AJAX`/`XHR`) to download data. And you can try to use this url with`requests`and`BeautifulSoup`

I found it uses url:

https://ark.intel.com/libs/apps/intel/support/ark/advancedFilterSearch?productType=873&1_Filter-Family=595&2_StatusCodeText=4&forwardPath=/content/www/us/en/ark/search/featurefilter.html&pageNo=1

I didn't check if `requests` will need special settings (ie. cookies, headers) to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Puppeteer to 'control' the dynamic web page, and scrape it with BS.

See here : https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/tree/master/examples